# Ming SWF markup and swfrender not giving correct output

Tags: php, flash, libming

I'm working on an application that uses Ming through the PHP extension to generate SWF files. This works great until someone needs to print something, so we create a PDF that uses a static image instead of flash. Currently we're using a custom solution that turns Flash into another format via Quicktime, but we want to get rid of needing a special box just for conversion.

I found SWFTools which looks like the perfect solution. I installed it on the web server and can call it from my app, but it's not generating the exact same output as the Flash version. I'm getting 33 errors with my test file, with two errors that repeat quite a bit:

```
array
  0 => string 'Error: ID 5 unknown' (length=19)
  ...
  3 => string 'Warning: Shape doesn't start with a moveTo' (length=42)
  ...
  33 => string 'Error: ID 133 unknown' (length=21)
```

The resulting file ends up with a few missing shapes if I run swfrender with -l (but overall not bad), but without -l I seem to get the correct number of shapes but rendered incorrectly (for example, a square might have 3 sides correct, and then fill from the 4th side to a random corner of the image).

Is there a known incompatibility between ming and SWFTools or is there something I can do to clear up these errors?

I'm using ming 0.4.4 and swftools-2011-01-23-1815 on CentOS 5.5, and PHP 5.3.6 (custom compiled).